# testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter Reports skipped tests of maven build to all xml files

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm using **maven fail safe plugin** with **integration test** phase and **verify** goal.

I have one module with 60 integration test classes.
in 4 of these classes I have an enabled=false test (total of 4).
when the build finishes it generates a xml file for each class but adding all 4 of these tests to all of the xmls.
When summing the results I get 240 falsely skipped tests.
Does anyone encountered this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the version of the surefire plugin?